# How can I split a single buffer into two panes that track the scroll of each other in vim?

Tags: vim

I have one buffer that I'd like to split into two vertical panes with the bottom of the right pane starting where the left pane ends. I understand how to split the panes, but is there any way to link them in vim without a plugin? If it's not possible, a plugin to do this would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Split the document into two panes, and then in each pane `:set scrollbind`.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Scrolling_synchronously

Comment: While it's possible to do what I'm looking for with this, it requires quite a bit of tweaking to get it right. Is there any way to enforce `the bottom of the right pane starting where the left pane ends` even if the size of the panes changes?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to have the same buffer in multiple columns continuously, like reading a book, there's the [MPage plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4545) that offers this.